# Error in App.js when trying to launch local React testing when switching to using hooks

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working on a project for my internet programming class and I'm not quite sure where I made my mistake here. I had this project at least running and able to test locally up until last night when I switched to using hooks (or trying to anyway). When I run `npm start` this is what logs into the console on Firefox.

```
Uncaught TypeError: this is undefined
    App App.js:67
    React 11
    workLoop scheduler.development.js:266
    flushWork scheduler.development.js:239
    performWorkUntilDeadline scheduler.development.js:533
    js scheduler.development.js:571
    js scheduler.development.js:633
    factory react refresh:6
    Webpack 24
App.js:67
    App App.js:67
    React 11
    performConcurrentWorkOnRoot self-hosted:1406
    workLoop scheduler.development.js:266
    flushWork scheduler.development.js:239
    performWorkUntilDeadline scheduler.development.js:533
    (Async: EventHandlerNonNull)
    js scheduler.development.js:571
    js scheduler.development.js:633
    factory react refresh:6
    Webpack 24
```

I had not changed any of my import statements, I had only added `useState`. VSCode shows me no errors in my code, so I believe something is out of place, but that's why I'm here to ask.

```
//import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import './form.css';
import React, { useState } from 'react';













function App(){


  const [showText, setShowText] = useState(0);

  const radioHandler = (showText) => {
    setShowText(showText);
  };

  




  // constructor = (props) => {
  //   super(props);
  //   this.state = {
  //     status: 0
  //   };
  //   handleInputChange = handleInputChange.bind(this);
  //   handleSubmit = handleSubmit.bind(this);
  // }

  const handleInputChange = (event, value) => {
    console.log(value);
  }

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  }










  return (
    <div className="form_css">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="general_info_container">
          <div className="name_container">
            <label className="f_name">First Name:</label>
            <input
              name="f_name"
              type="text"
              value={this.state.f_name}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              placeholder="Please enter your first name"
            />

            <label className="m_name">Middle Initial:</label>
            <input
              name="m_name"
              type="text"
              value={this.state.m_name}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              placeholder="Please enter your middle initial"
            />

            <label className="l_name">Last Name:</label>
            <input
              name="l_name"
              type="text"
              value={this.state.l_name}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              placeholder="Please enter your last name"
            />
          </div>

          <div className="address_container">
            <label>Street:</label>
            <input
              className="street"
              type="text"
              value={this.state.street}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              placeholder="123 Main Street"
            />

            <label>City:</label>
            <input
              className="city"
              type="text"
              value={this.state.city}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              placeholder="City Name"
            />

            <label>State:</label>
            <input
              className="state"
              type="text"
              value={this.state.state}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              placeholder="New York"
            />

            <label>Zip Code:</label>
            <input
              className="zip_code"
              type="number"
              value={this.state.zip_code}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              placeholder="12345"
            />
          </div>

          <div>
            <label>
              Have you exercised regularly within the past six (6) months?
            </label>
            <input
              className="exr_yes"
              type="radio"
              value="true"
              onChange={handleInputChange}
            />
            <input
              className="exr_no"
              type="radio"
              value="false"
              onChange={handleInputChange}
            />

            <br></br>

            {/* Testing radio button hide/show */}
            <label>Do you have any chonic medical conditions? TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST</label>
            <input
              className="chronic_yes"
              type="radio"
              value="true"
              checked={showText === 1}
              onClick={(e) => radioHandler(1)}
            />
            <input
              className="chronic_no"
              type="radio"
              value="false"
              checked={showText === 2}
              onClick={(e) => radioHandler(2)}
            />
            {showText === 1 && 
              <div>
                <p>Test showing</p>
              </div>}
              {showText === 2 & <p></p>}
            
            

















            <div>
              <label>Please enter any chronic conditions you have below:</label>
              <input
                className="chronic_medical"
                type="text"
                value={this.state.chronic_show}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
              />
            </div>
            {/* Testing radio button hide/show

            {/* Testing radio button hide/show */}
            <label>Are you currently taking any medication?</label>
            <input
              className="meds_yes"
              type="radio"
              value="chronic"
              onClick={(e) => radioHandler(1)}
            />
            <input
              className="meds_no"
              type="radio"
              value="chronic"
              onClick={(e) => radioHandler(2)}
            />

            <div id="meds_show">
              <label>Please list any medications you take below:</label>
              <input
                className="meds_show"
                type="text"
                value={this.state.meds_show}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
              />
            </div>
            {/* Testing radio button hide/show */}

            {/* Testing radio button hide/show */}
            <label>Do you, or have you had, any injuries?</label>
            <input
              className="injury_yes"
              type="radio"
              value="ture"
              onChange={handleInputChange}
            />
            <input
              className="injnury_no"
              type="radio"
              value="false"
              onChange={handleInputChange}
            />

            <div id="injury_show">
              <label>
                Please enter any injuries you have had in the past below:
              </label>
              <input
                className="injury_show"
                type="text"
                value={this.state.injury_show}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
              />
            </div>
            {/* Testing radio button hide/show */}

            <label>
              Has a doctor ever suggested you only participate in medically
              supervised exercise?
            </label>
            <input
              className="supexr_yes"
              type="radio"
              value={this.state.supexr_yes}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
            />
            <input
              className="supexr_no"
              type="radio"
              value={this.state.supexr_no}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}








export default App;
```

And please, if you have any tips for a beginner they would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you exactly what is going wrong: `this` is being referenced and is undefined.
I can see you've commented out some lines, which looks as though you've moved away from using Class components to Functional components. Class components *would* understand `this`, but as you're now using a Functional component constructs like `this.state.f_name` are meaningless.

I don't want to re-write your code, but just want to point out that you probably want to do something like:

```
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("");
....
const handleInputChange = (event, value) => {
    if(event.target.name == 'f_name'){
         setFirstName(value);
    }
    console.log(value);
  }
...
            <input
              name="f_name"
              type="text"
              value={firstName}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              placeholder="Please enter your first name"
            />
```

You need to do something similar for all other input fields, and then tidy up the code.

I suggest you always start with something small (remove all other fields and just get one field working).
https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html is an external starting place to get a better understanding of React. Happy coding.

Comment: That makes much more sense now. We had started much smaller in class, and largely I had it all working until I switched away from using classes. We've only just gotten into covering hooks this week. Can I ask what it is you recommend I work on tidying?

Thank you!

Comment: I'd suggest you create a useState hook for each of your fields *to begin with*. Eventually, all your useState hooks can be combined into a single hook that uses an object - similar to the suggestion given by Zahid Hasan. I would take this slower approach because simple concepts need to make sense first, and there are many ways to refactor the code for improvement.

Answer (score 1):

You use `this.state` in your input field value but you are using hooks. You can create all your state variable using useState. Like the below:

```
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState({
    f_name: '',
    m_name: '',
    ...

})

return (
    <div>
      ...
      <input
          name="f_name"
          type="text"
          value={inputValue.f_name}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          placeholder="Please enter your first name"
      />
    </div>
)
```